# Select All Text Areas And Add into one Textarea

Tags: php, javascript

Hello im currently writing my own javascript/PHP css editor and i have it explode the file into tags and its all echoed out into separate text areas from a loop, i was wondering if its possible to scan the page with javascript and get all the content from all the text areas and add them into one variable or one text-area, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function getTextAreasText() {
      var all = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        var values = "";
        for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
            values += all[i].value;
        }
      return values;
    }
.
.
.
.
var allTexts = getTextAreasText();
```

Comment: works a charm thanks does what its supposed to. now my next question is how would i also them addon a h1 before each one thats directly before each textarea

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

If you are familiar with jquery, this is really simple.  You would do something like:

```
var compiled_content = '';
$.('.name_of_class_to_extract').each(function() {
    compiled_content += $(this).html();
});
```

This would give you all HTML content from the specified class ('name_of_class_to_extract') in the variable compiled_content.  You could then insert this content into another element like:

```
$('.class_to_inseert').html(compiled_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "";
$("textarea").each(function(){
  a += $(this).text();
  $(this).prepend("<h1>" + "someValue" + "</h1>") //prepend some markup before each textarea
});
a //concatenated data
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes possible. Edit following lines for yourself

```
// jquery code
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'get_content_via.php',
        type : 'GET',
        data : 'maybe_use_filename',
        success:function(data){
            var splittedData = data.split("your_seperator"); // like explode
            for( var i = 0 ; i < splittedData.lenght ; i++){
                $('#targetInput').append(splittedData[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wont need ajax its in the current page.

Comment: who mentioned AJAX?  Posting snippets of your own code that appear to be in no way related to the OP's problem is _not_ helpful!

Comment: if you get full css content must be use ajax and php